# Circles intersecting at A and B

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

**Question**:

> Two given circles intersect at A and B. A straight line through B meets the circles again at C and D. Prove that CD is greatest when it is parallel to the line joining the centres

**My attempt**:

I made this diagram on Paint.NET:

[image]

Here CD is the required line parallel to the line $MNOP$ joining the centers N and O, and EF is another line not parallel to $MNOP$. Both CD and EF pass through point B.
I know I have to prove that $CD > EF$.

But I don't know how to solve this problem. And I need hints.

Comment: Do you assume that both circles are of the same size?

Comment: @AxelKemper This is not given in the question. So, no, I do not assume that both circles are of same size.